# Csv file reader

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am supposed to create a python function that reads csv files. I have most of it written, there are just a few problems that I am having. First, my mean, min, and max are all giving me the same numbers, and I don't know what's wrong. Lastly, I can't figure out how to work the standard deviation. I would really appreciate the help.
I am also supposed to get a minimum of 0.580, a maximum of 1.552, a mean of 1.0228, and a standard deviation of 0.14654.
Also, on the data points, I am only supposed to use column 2.

```
import csv
import statistics

def fileread03 (file):
    Data=[]
    with open(file, newline='') as In_file:
        reader=csv.reader(In_file, delimiter=",")
        Header=False
        for row in reader:
            if Header:
                Header=True
                HeaderInfo=row
        else:
            Data.append(float(row[1]))

    avg=statistics.mean(Data)
    mini=min(Data)
    maxi=max(Data)

    print (file,"Column 2 has minimum of",mini,"and maximum of",maxi)      
    print (file,"Column 2 has a mean of","%f"%(avg),"with","%d"%(reader.line_num),"data points")
    print (file,"Column 2 standard deviation is %s"%(statistics.stdev(Data)))
```

I haven't figured out how to post my data as a link, so i will just paste it. I apologize.

```
1,1.03022387
2,1.038002145
3,1.035830101
4,1.034994363
5,1.031323334
6,1.038452321
7,1.043062609
8,1.038032379
9,1.0364557
10,1.032418438
11,1.035486002
12,1.034489151
13,1.042182439
14,1.036726578
15,1.040725664
16,1.04258192
17,1.033622994
18,1.0353206
19,1.036432256
20,1.039528582
21,1.037882773
22,1.03727257
23,1.037687353
24,1.031052011
25,1.03824202
26,1.042547636
27,1.041188157
28,1.040335043
29,1.039175566
30,1.039636431
31,1.037803898
32,1.041778196
33,1.034893874
34,1.031176139
35,1.033263496
36,1.043093701
37,1.043429697
38,1.001
39,1.04113086
40,1.037847987
41,1.032391964
42,1.040356843
43,1.037036769
44,1.039085609
45,1.036347304
46,1.040578085
47,1.037387121
48,1.038344488
49,1.031850887
50,1.040082844
51,0.985461896
52,0.826852007
53,0.797357281
54,1.005512301
55,1.00039709
56,1.222802255
57,1.142375769
58,1.352032893
59,1.112897551
60,0.87815325
61,1.105341595
62,1.068324568
63,0.677663188
64,0.796153856
65,1.008681073
66,0.580124268
67,1.114469402
68,0.775473003
69,0.662000558
70,1.215449602
71,1.190480987
72,1.042210619
73,0.779978889
74,0.978878568
75,1.103720987
76,1.171154216
77,1.552026816
78,0.863948023
79,0.851098845
80,0.838314475
81,0.858669262
82,1.019072619
83,0.787732957
84,0.813981183
85,1.199212974
86,0.846172396
87,1.165392635
88,1.14476665
89,1.34478376
90,1.501
91,1.018674479
92,1.092147525
93,0.827845253
94,0.941279736
95,0.892973283
96,1.168058418
97,0.779913496
98,1.174240444
99,1.078392083
100,1.084858149
```

Comment: First of all, please post your code here instead of linking a screenshot. Screenshots are hard to read usually and hard for people who are helping to replicate. And, please provide what values are you getting, what do you expect them to be.

Comment: you need to indent your else block one more level. this has to be at the same indentation level as your if block

Comment: thank you, I completely looked over that. @JustinEzequiel

Answer (score 0):

you need to indent the 'else' block, here is my version :

```
def fileread03(file):
Data=[]
stats = {}
with open(file, newline='') as In_file:
    reader=csv.reader(In_file, delimiter=",")
    Header=False
    for row in reader:
        if Header:
            Header=True
            HeaderInfo=row
        else:
            Data.append(float(row[1]))

stats['avg'] = statistics.mean(Data)
stats['min'] = min(Data)
stats['max'] = max(Data)
return stats
```

and the result looks like when executing :

```
file_stats = fileread03('data-stackOver.csv')
```

Out:

```
{'avg': 1.02278293901, 'min': 0.580124268, 'max': 1.552026816}
```